# Statsmodels seasonal ARIMA: only monthly and quarterly periods are supported

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am implementing seasonal ARIMA in Python and I am using Statsmodels 0.7.0. I am calling the function statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_select_order with a 15 minutes periodic data in argument. I am getting this error:

> "Only monthly and quarterly periods are supported. Please report or
>   send a pull request if you want this extended."

I do not find a way to apply seasonal ARIMA to data with different periods.

[Here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/x13.py) is the source code I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an x13 limitation not statsmodels. You can modify the Fortran in x13, but I doubt you'd really want to go down that route. Also, this is orthogonal to seasonal ARIMA. There is not yet any seasonal ARIMA order selection AFAIK. There is a `sm.tsa.stattools.arma_order_select_ic` that may do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I tried sm.tsa.stattools.arma_order_select_ic and It did not work for me. It seems like I should apply a seasonal model. Could you please explain more how to modify the Fortran in x13.

Comment: You're on your own there. Have a look through the x13 manual. They mention how you might do this and why it's a bad idea if I recall correctly. There are also hard-coded constraints on the number of observations that you'll need to fix.